# Can I open a mysql 5.1 database from mysql 5.5?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL 5.1 database (The data files in *F:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1*), but I'd like to open the database from MySQL 5.5 on my new computer.  I don't have MySQL 5.1 running any longer because my old computer's motherboard failed, and all I have is the hard drive where my 5.1 database resides.

Is there a way to open the old MySQL 5.1 database from MySQL 5.5?

I should add that my database is InnoDB (I think).  I had another database that was MyISAM and I was able to open it in MySQL 5.5 just by copying the old database directory over to the new MySQL data directory.

Comment: The 5.1 databases were on my computer which no longer works, so I got a new computer and installed a fresh MySQL 5.5.  Now I'm trying to access my 5.1 databases through the new MySQL 5.5 install.

Comment: Essentially, what you have is a snapshot at time of mobo failure. You should just be able to redirect path to the the data from the 5.1 databases in your my.ini file. There maybe a couple of more steps but should work.

Answer (score 1):

In the Linux world you can simply copy the file system /var/lib/mysql/[yourdbfolder] into the new file system.  You then have to run mysqlcheck --repair but all should be good after that.

Comment: Will this work for InnoDB databases?  After further investigation I realized I have one MyISAM database and two InnoDB databases.  I was able to follow your instructions for the MyISAM database and it worked.   Also, I'm on Windows.

Comment: Do you have innodb_file_per_table set?

Comment: No, I don't believe so, as there are no .ibd files in the database directory.